# WSO2 ESB 5.0.0 - How to get registry value to property mediator

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Hi is there a way to get a registry value to a property mediator in ESB 5.0.0

Comment: Need to get a text value such as user name, which should be a registry value to a property mediator in a mediation flow.

Answer (score 1):

XML in registry:

```
<property name="xmlfile" expression="get-property('registry', 'gov:/xml/body.xml')" type="OM" />
```

Registry property:

```
<property name="regProperty" expression="get-property('registry', 'gov:/data/xml/collectionx@abc')"/>
```

Ref: http://movingaheadblog.blogspot.com/search?q=registry

Comment: Hi Bhathiya, thanks for the reply. Usually when referring a Governance registry value (Eg : in Named Endpoints) the reference is shown as `gov:data/directory/test.xml`. Here in your exmaple the line
`gov:/data/xml/collectionx@abc` is hard to understand. Could you please explain it to me, appreciate the help.

Comment: Here `collection` is a directory in the registry. `abc` is a property of that directory. If you browse registry in management console, you can see there are properties for every collection (directory) in registry.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the configuration values / parameters or constants into a `global.xml` file and have it managed in a governance registry.

For example, the `global.xml` can be like the following.

```
    <custom>
        <userName>xyz</userName>
        <Type>FOR</Type>
    </custom>
```

We can load the parameters through a sequence and then use the parameters by reusing the sequence file.

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="loadProperties_seq">
   <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="localProperties" expression="get-property('registry', 'gov:/common/utils/properties/global.xml')" scope="default" type="OM"/>
</sequence>
```

Refer the properties..

```
<property name="url_reg" expression="//custom/userName"/>       
<property name="user_reg" expression="//custom/Type"/>
```

Comment: Can anyone also please let me know how to get the value from json message whcih is stored in registry. It would be really helpful

Comment: @2437850 you can refer the message or values similar to the example in the above answer